# tablesorterPager does not work. (with error message)

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, pager

I am sorting my table with tablesorter.
It works well.
As my consequences are growing longer, I am needed to get pager.
I used tablesorterPager, it is not working.

Error message is below.

```
jquery.tablesorter.pager.js:949 Uncaught TypeError: ts.debug is not a function
at init (jquery.tablesorter.pager.js:949)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.tablesorter.pager.js:1182)
at Function.each (jquery-2.1.4.js:374)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.4.js:139)
at jQuery.fn.init.$this.construct [as tablesorterPager] (jquery.tablesorter.pager.js:1179)
at Object.success (players.php:140)
at fire (jquery-2.1.4.js:3099)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.js:3211)
at done (jquery-2.1.4.js:8264)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.4.js:8605)
```

ajax is

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/web1/ice_hockey/report/call_report.php",
        type : "post",
        data : params,
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data){

    $('.b7').append('<table>').append(table_header(reportType));
    $('#caption').hide();

    $('table').attr('id', 'tb');
    $('table').addClass('tablesorter');

    var table_body = ''

    $.each(data, function(i, item){ 
        table_body += '<tr>';
        for(var e in item){
            table_body += '<td>' + item[e] + '</td>';
            }
            table_body += '</tr>';
            }); 


    $('tbody').append(table_body).trigger('applyWidgets');
    $('#tb').after(pager)

    var resort = true;
    $('table').trigger('update', [resort]);

    $('#tb').tablesorter()
            .tablesorterPager({
                        container: $("#pager")
                    });
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText); 
    }
});

});
```

My pager is below and it is going after table tag.

```
var pager = '<div id="pager" class="tablesorterPager">' +
        '<form><img src="/web1/ice_hockey/css/pager/icons/first.png" class="first">'+
        '<img src="/web1/ice_hockey/css/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev">'+
        '<input type="text" class="pagedisplay">'+
        '<img src="/web1/ice_hockey/css/pager/icons/next.png" class="next">'+
        '<img src="/web1/ice_hockey/css/pager/icons/last.png" class="last">'+
        '<select class="pagesize">'+
            '<option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>'+
            '<option value="20">20</option>'+
            '<option value="30">30</option>'+
            '<option value="40">40</option>'+
        ' </select>'+
        ' </form>'+
    '</div>';
```

I want to know when that error occurs how to resolve that error.
I think my description is can be little. If so let me know with anything needed. Thanks always!

Answer (score 1):

Assure that you use the last version: '2.31.1' "jquery.tablesorter.combined.js" or/and "jquery.tablesorter.js"

I got the same problem with the version '2.25.4':

```
init = function(table, settings) {
                var t, ctrls, fxn, $el,
                c = table.config,
                wo = c.widgetOptions,
                debug = ts.debug(c, 'pager'), *** error here ***

jquery-3.1.1.js:3846 jQuery.Deferred exception: ts.debug is not a function TypeError: ts.debug is not a function
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem for me!